# Mounting volume with readonly access for a host

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to mount volume where host has readonly access. Host belongs to a group which can read contents from a given folder. I mount it to my docker image, but inside the container I get permission denied error. I also cannot change owner or permissions inside the container - Operation not permitted/Permission denied error.

`docker run -i -t -v /path/to/dir:/path/to/dir:Z image /bin/bash`

Is there a way to access contents from a given folder inside the container? How?

Comment: When you say "host has readonly access", do you mean that the user running docker on the host only has read only permissions to the folder?

Comment: yes, exactly, "host" is a user running docker

Comment: It looks like you have `selinux` enabled, and so there could be a number of reasons why you get the error. You can check the context on the folder - `ls -lZa` to see if it matches with the context of the running container - `docker inspect -f '{{ .ProcessLabel }}' <image name>`. You could also check the host system logs for selinux denial messages to understand why the denial is happening. Without these additional details, it's hard to provide a definitive answer.